# solving the $ \varepsilon_{ijk}\varepsilon_{lmn}$(Levi Civita)

Tags: determinant, mathematical-physics, mathematica

How can I solve this :
$ \varepsilon_{ijk}\varepsilon_{lmn}=??$
I know that It can be solve with 2 determinants but I don't know how.and I don't what are the determinants!

Comment: What is $\varepsilon_{ijk}$ ?

Comment: Levi-Civita symbol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that $\varepsilon_{ijk}$ is the [Levi-Civita-symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol). The tricky think is  that in this notation you actually already use Einsteins sum convention. In fact you can solve it by a single determinant.

\begin{align}
\varepsilon_{ijk}\varepsilon_{lmn} & = \det\begin{pmatrix}
\delta_{il} & \delta_{im}& \delta_{in}\\
\delta_{jl} & \delta_{jm}& \delta_{jn}\\
\delta_{kl} & \delta_{km}& \delta_{kn}\\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

Comment: why this determinant is true??
where did it come from?!

Comment: @aaa To see it is true you just can calculate both sides. Where does it come from? Well the levi civita tensor is a total antisymmetric 3 linear form on a 3 dimensional space. Up to a constant it must be the determinant. From the definition we can see that $\varepsilon_{ijk} = e_i (e_j\times e_k)$ which can be written as a determinant.

Comment: I saw this solution .[link](http://www.thphys.uni-heidelberg.de/~hefft/vk1/k9/971b1e.htm) and I accepted that the first determinant is true but I cant understand the second one.the second one is for the second Levi Civita

Comment: @aaa you mean because the second is transposed ?

Comment: Yes that's right!!when you transposed a matric the determinant of that will be change!isn't it?

Comment: @aaa no the determinant isn't change by transposing a matrix

Comment: oh!what a bad mistake!thx a lot